# Pass window.innerWidth/innerHeight as component props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want my React component to stretch to certain `width` and `height`, passed as props. Default values for `width` and `height` are supposed to be `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`, respectively.

But, when I do, something like:

```
const MyComponent = ({width=window.innerWidth, height=window.innerHeight}) => (
   <div style={{width,height}} />
)
```

I'll get my default values `undefined`, is there a way I can fix that?
Thanks.

Comment: It usually works that way. Can you provide more context? Is it a web app?

Comment: @Mikey this should work, if you `console.log(window)` in your app what do you get?